# How to use driver object in webdriverio with appium

Tags: javascript, testing, appium, webdriver-io

While testing with appium and webdriverio, there should be a `driver` global object like the `browser` object, but when I try using it the test doesn't compile because it doesn't exist!
it's mentioned here:

https://webdriver.io/docs/browserobject.html

and it's needed for all appium's native commands in here:

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/appium.html

But I don't know how to get it working. (for the `browser` object I just use it, although the IDE doesn't recognize it, but it works, on contrast to the `driver` object)

Edit: I tried using `browser` object in place of `driver` and it worked for `browser.isMobile` and `browser.lock(5)` (it locked the screen for 5 seconds), but I didn't try the more advanced uses yet (as switching the context for example) so my question: is there a difference between `driver` and `browser`?!

Comment: I find that doc confusing too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(browser === driver);
> true
```

so both should be basically the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what version did you try this on?

Comment: appium: 1.15.1
webdriverio: 5.16.7
@wdio/appium-service: 5.16.5